# sorting of array by date (requiring explode)

Tags: php

I am struggling to sort an array containing dates. I've try several things without success to sort this array (extracting date with explode/strtotime, then combining and array_multisort ...), and I'm still stuck.

I work with an array like that:

```
array (
[0] => "blabla 2015-01-01"
[1] => "blabla2 2016-01-01"
[2] => "blabla3 2010-01-01"
)
```

My goal would be to sort this array by the date (DESC or ASC)
ps: between blabla and the date there is a tabulation

I would be very thankful to anyone who can give me a bit of help
Thanks

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow! To help you, we need to see your code _in the question_. Please gather the relevant code and post it here. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your input is stored in variable `$data`, and the strings are TAB-delimited, you can do the following:

```
usort($data, function ($a, $b) {
    return strcmp(explode("\t", $a)[1], explode("\t", $b)[1]);
});
```

This looks only at the second field in the comparisons.

Comment: hello, thanks for answering!. is that possible to do the same with explode to extract the date ? (in my real working array the date field is not at the end)

Comment: oh, is there a way to check if the usort function did "effectively" (or not) sort the array ?

Comment: It returns `false` if for some reason the `usort` fails, but that only happens if the array passed in the first argument is not an array. Otherwise you can be sure the array is sorted by it.

Comment: Hum, understood. What I mean was " how to check if the usort affect the order of the values of the array "? (in some cases my array will be initially correctly sorted and the usort will not re-order the values and in other cases my array will not be initially sorted and the usort fonction will re-order the array) ...

Comment: You found it ;)